# How do you prove that something is greater than the other?

Tags: analysis

I aim to prove that $2n + 7 < 2^{n}$ for all integers $n \geq 4$. By trying out some $n$'s, it is obvious that this will be true for all integers $n \geq 4$. But that is obviously not a proof. Any advice?

Comment: This calls for proof by induction

Answer (score 2):

You almost found the proof (at least one proof), by **induction**

So

1. For $n=4$ this holds
2. Trying cases hints it holds for all $n$
3. To make it more complete, assume it holds for some $k \ge 4$
4. Show that if it holds for $k$, it also holds for $k+1$
5. Then it holds for all $n \ge 4$! Yes

This above **method of mathematical induction**, describes the process you already thought, just in more formal terms!